# What is a jumper?

Tags: motor, processor, jumper

I have solved the circle problem, but now have another. What is a jumper, and how should it be plugged into D7, D8, D9 and D10? I can't find them in the list of materials, I don't know what they look like or what to do. I know these questions are probably pretty simple to solve, hopefully I'll learn quickly! Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumper_%28computing%29

Comment: A jumper is sometimes called a sweater or pullover. Or do you mean a long jumper, or high jumper? Is a pole vaulter a jumper or not?

Comment: Jessica, there is not enough information for us to understand the question. D7-D10 on what piece of hardware? Please provide **all** relevant information.

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance, this is the first time in my life I have tried anything like this, I am barely aware what is relevant and what isn't! The hardware I think is an Arduino NG with Atmega8. Does that make it answerable?

Comment: @Jessica - You probably should have referred to the manual I linked to in my answer, and given the full quote about "D7, D8, D9, D10" in context.  Keep in mind that many of the people looking at any new questions you make will not have seen any of your earlier questions, so each question needs to stand alone.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the [Dagu Doodle Bot manual I see linked](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B__O096vyVYqSXZzOVZ6YXl5WHM/view?pli=1) in [your other question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/204284/robot-turns-in-circles-only), you need to find some of these:

[image]

They slide onto the pin header to connect 2 pins together. Hopefully you have them in your kit.  If not, and you don't expect to take the jumpers off very often, you could just solder a wire between the pins instead.